# How to restart openssl on debian

Tags: debian, openssl

I have made some changes in `openssl.cnf` and wants to restart service. Normally I would just restart machine for changes to take effect but I don't want to restart machine. Tried `sudo systemctl restart openssl` but it didn't work as there is no such service.

How to I restart or reload openssl after making changes in configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all running processes that you might want to restart after an openssl change with:

```
ps -p $(grep -El 'libssl.so|libcrypto.so' /proc/*/maps|sed -r 's/\/proc\/([0-9]+)\/maps/\1/'|sort -nu)
```

The command search in the memory maps of each process and look for some of the openssl libs that are used by that command. Then it is displaying the process details for each match.

E.g. for `systemd-journal` process:

```
[root@laptop-rh ~]# grep -E 'libssl.so|libcrypto.so' /proc/938/maps
7f08dc800000-7f08dc8ad000 r--p 00000000 00:26 6540246                    /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.3.0.9
7f08dc8ad000-7f08dcb11000 r-xp 000ad000 00:26 6540246                    /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.3.0.9
7f08dcb11000-7f08dcbca000 r--p 00311000 00:26 6540246                    /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.3.0.9
7f08dcbca000-7f08dcc21000 r--p 003ca000 00:26 6540246                    /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.3.0.9
7f08dcc21000-7f08dcc24000 rw-p 00421000 00:26 6540246                    /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.3.0.9
[root@laptop-rh ~]# ps -p 938
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
    938 ?        00:00:10 systemd-journal
[root@laptop-rh ~]#
```

See also [checkrestart](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/checkrestart.1.html).

Comment: Caveat: `libssl.so libcrypto.so` are OpenSSL, but `libssl3.so libcrypt.so libcryptosetup.so` which your command (often) finds are not. And while debian-packaged programs use dynamic linking, programs you build yourself (including tools like pip or npm or scripts you download from some site somewhere) may not, and thus won't be found.

Comment: Thank you. You are right.  I edited my answer.

Answer (score 5):

`openssl` is command line tool and library. There is no daemon to restart.

On next execution of `openssl` or program which use `openssl` library the config will be read.

If it is involved web server you will need to restart it.

Comment: But once I changed config, I was still getting same error in WordPress for which I made changes in config. I was expecting that WordPress will read new changes but it didn't Then I restarted machine and error was fixed.

Comment: @FrankMartin, you miss this point (about WordPress). You need to restart apache

Comment: You are right, I found it. I actually had to restart `php-fpm`